# C# Log Socket Connections

Tags: c#, sockets, logging, connection

I've no idea how I would go about this but I'm assuming that it is possible in some way, shape or form.

1. If I have a server that allow multiple connections to it through one port, is there a way I can make some sort of log of the connections, so that I could choose a certain connection to send a message to? Also if this is possible.
2. Is it also possible to do the same with connections through *`different`* ports?
3. How would I go about this? I'm fairly new to C# so not very experienced - any help is greatly appreciated!

Basically I want `3` clients to connect to a server. The clients will all send a message to the server, and the server will wait for a message from each client before replying to them, in the order in which the messages were sent.

I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `so that I could choose a certain connect to send a message` explain more in detail what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: This is more related to network programming, not specific to any language. How about reading some docs before coding?

Comment: I4V you can do socket programming with .NET so his question is some what valid the OP needs to explain more in detail what they are trying to do

Comment: I've added detail. Hopefully it is more helpful now.

Comment: Would SignalR be a viable option?

Comment: No, afraid not. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TCP/IP, this is very much possible - the `Socket` that listens for incoming connections only does that - it does not handle the communication with each individual socket. Instead, the `Accept()` and `BeginAccept()` methods return a new `Socket` instance for each client that connects.

So the `Socket` instance you get when a client connects only receives messages from that client, and sending a message on that socket sends it to only that client.

Keeping track of which connection sent what - and which came first - will be more of a challenge, but definately possible.

If you are using UDP though things are a bit different, you would need to use a custom means of identifying each client.

Comment: I am using TCP/IP so thank you for this. It has made it a lot more clearer, and a good starting point. Thank you very much :)